# JUnit 5 and Mockito: Mocking getters and setters

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

How to mock getter-setter method in the below implementation?

```
MyClass obj=new MyClass();

obj.getName().setFirstName("hello"); // How to Mock this part ?
```

**Testing**

```
@Mock
MyClass obj;

@Test
void testing(){

  doNothing().when(obj).getName().setName(anyString()); //this doesn't work

}
```

Comment: Mock / spy the return value of `obj.getName()` and then expect `setFirstName` to be called on that mock.

Comment: If you actually have the `new MyClass` statement right before the line you want to test, then you are basically out of luck already and it is quite questionable what you want to actually test at all and what sense the code makes in the first place!

Comment: It is _generally_ a better idea not to mock plain data objects; if `Name` is just a POJO, you don't need a mock. Mocks are for _behavior_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that there are two objects involved: your mocked `MyClass` and the object returned by `getName()`.  You need to mock both of them.

```
@Mock
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
@Mock
MyName name = new MyName();
...
when(obj).getName().theReturn(name);
when(name).setName(anyString());
```

This allows you to define the behavior of both objects separately.  See @Yassin's answer if you want to use `Mokito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` feature which mocks the complete call chain.

Obviously if you are trying to test whether or not a class set/get work and return the right stuff should be done on a concrete instance of the class and not on a mock object.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to add the flag `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` to your mock.

```
// if your mock is instantiated with the annotation
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
MyClass obj;

// if your mock is instantiated with the factory method
MyClass obj = Mockito.mock(MyClass.class, Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set a value, just define the value which will getter return.

```
when(obj.getName()).thenReturn("hello");
```